# Determining Which Statistician Has The Greatest Posterior Degree of Belief

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I am given that we have data $s$ and that there are $\textbf{Two}$ statisticians analyzing these data using the same sampling model but with different priors, and they are asked to assess a hypothesis $H_0$.

Both statisticians report a Bayes factor in favor of $H_0$ equal to $100$

$\textbf{Statistician I}$ assigned a prior probability $\frac{1}{2}$ to $H_0$

$\textbf{statistician II}$ assigned prior probability $\frac{1}{4}$ to $H_0$

How do we determine which statistician has the greatest posterior degree of belief in $H_0$ being true?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> How do we determine which statistician has the greatest posterior degree of belief in $H_0$ being true?

having the same Bayes Factor, the posterior degree of belief in $H_0$ is greater for Stat I  as Stat II gives a bigger prior probability to $H_1$

---

The decision in favour of $H_0$ is governed by the following rule:

$$\frac{P(\theta=\theta_0)}{P(\theta=\theta_1)}\times \underbrace{\frac{p(\mathbf{x}|\theta_0)}{p(\mathbf{x}|\theta_1)}}_{\text{Bayes Factor}}>1$$

the likelihood ratio is called "Bayes Factor"

Thus for Stat 1 the decision rule is 1:1 while for Stat II the decision rule is 1:3. This means that the degree of belief in $H_0$ is greater for Stat  I who beliefs the two hypotheses are equal in probability. Stat II beliefs that $H_1$ is more probabily. Decision could change after seeing the data, but as per the fact that BF is the same for both...

Comment: How do we calculate the posterior degree of belief in $H_0$?

Comment: @VirgOpta : added some details, hope this helps

Comment: thanks that helps!